# Ext.js ComboBox Not Displaying JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, extjs, combobox

I've checked, checked and checked again and can't get the comboBox to display the data.

The JSON array is:

```
{"DepartmentData":[{"Department":"Company
Holidays","DepartmentHeadUserID":"74"},{"Department":"Despatch"
,"DepartmentHeadUserID":"70"},{"Department":"Fabric 
Shades","DepartmentHeadUserID":"159"}]}...
```

Which is loading perfectly fine but for some reason the comboBox is not using the array to populate.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var comboStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,

    url: 'includes/DataGet.php',
    storeId: 'DepartmentData',

    root: 'DepartmentData',
    idProperty: 'Department',
    fields: ['Department','DepartmentHeadID'],
    });




    Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';




    var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 75,
    url: 'DataStore.php',
    frame:true,
    title: 'Holiday Request Form',
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 350,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',




    items: [

        new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel: 'Department',
        name: 'Department',
        id: 'Department',
        forceSelection: true,
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        lazyRender: true,
        store: comboStore,
        emptyText: 'Please Select...',
        mode: 'remote',
        displayField: 'Department',
        valueField: 'DepartmentHeadID',
        allowBlank: false
        }),
    ],

    buttons: [{
    text: 'Submit'
    },{
    text: 'Cancel'
    }]
});

 simple.render(document.body);

});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try changing this  fields: ['Department','DepartmentHeadID'], to  fields: ['Department','DepartmentHeadUSerID'],

Comment: And fix `valueField: 'DepartmentHeadID'` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You won't believe  this...

I was sending 2 JSON arrays from the PHP file and when I commented the second out to make this post it worked.

Seems I need to set & send params on the JSON Store and then use a switch statement in the PHP file to send back the required array.